# Must at least one bundle have the same name as the entity in hook_entity_info()?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm working with `hook_entity_info`, and I'm defining an entity which will have multiple bundles.

Do I need to define a bundle which has the same name as the entity, or will the base entity become entirely "abstract" once I define entity bundles?

In the below piece of code, I've defined a `setting` entity which has the bundle `generic`. Should `generic` really be called `setting`, or can i completely regard the entity as an "abstract" concept?

```
function settings_entity_info() {
  $info['setting'] = array(
    'access callback' => 'settings_entity_access',
    'admin ui' => array(
      'path' => 'admin/structure/settings',
      'controller class' => 'EntityOperationsDefaultAdminUIController',
    ),
    'base table' => 'setting',
    'bundle keys' => array(
      'bundle' => 'type',
    ),
    'bundles' => array(
      'generic' => array(
        'label' => t('Generic Setting'),
        'admin' => array(
          'path' => 'admin/structure/settings/generic',
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not required. It's not necessary to have a bundle whose machine name is the same machine name used for the entity type. And no, defining bundles doesn't make the entity more abstract in any way.

See, for example, [`node_entity_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_entity_info/7.x), where none of the content types (which are node bundles) is called *node*. Vice versa, in [`user_entity_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_entity_info/7.x) the only bundle is *user*.
What you can gather from the implementations of `hook_entity_info()` done from Drupal core modules is that entities with a single bundle use the same machine name for the bundle and the entity. That is not mandatory, though.

What Drupal assumes is that, if `hook_entity_info()` doesn't define any bundle, the entity has a single bundle named after the entity type. See [`entity_get_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_get_info/7.x).

```
    // If no bundle key is provided, assume a single bundle, named after
    // the entity type.
    if (empty($entity_info[$name]['entity keys']['bundle']) && empty($entity_info[$name]['bundles'])) {
      $entity_info[$name]['bundles'] = array(
        $name => array(
          'label' => $entity_info[$name]['label'],
        ),
      );
    }
```